# Multiple Azure App Gateway for Different namespaces in Azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to create an Application Gateway for AKS. My requirement is to create Multiple Application Gateways for each Namespace in AKS.

Is it possible to do so? And additionally can I use the Ingress controller for Load balancing for each namespace?

Comment: ok, what doesnt work?

Comment: I am able to create one app gateway and bind it to the AKS cluster. Is their any way via which I can create one more app gateway and attach it to the namespace or Nodes? 
I am looking for a direction or help on this.

Comment: yes, like you've done with the first one

Comment: I attached the APP gateway to the cluster not with Namespace. Is their any way by which I could attach the app gateway to the specific namespace in AKS?

Answer (score 1):

to sum it up, you can attach application gateway (or multiple ones) like you normally would. application gateways are not aware of k8s primitives, so they cannot really route to the namespace, they will route to the node, and your ingress\service should handle it.

but there's an [Application Gateway Ingress](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) available (current not GA), which can do that for you. you will define ingress resources and it will configure application gateway according to those. Not sure if it can configure multiple of those, but you dont really need multiple unless you exceed inbound ports.